# ServiceStack TypeSerializer: ISO8601 and culture with dot as TimeSeparator

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, servicestack, iso8601

This is my first question, handle with care.
On .Net 4.5.2 using c#, I found a strange behaviour on [ServiceStack.Text 4.5.6](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) serializing `DateTime`: if current culture time separator is dot (.) and the serialized `DateTime` is either local or rounded to seconds, the result of the serialization will have dot as time separator as well, even when using `DateHandler.ISO8601`. I made a simple test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("bn-IN");

    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var utcRoundedToSecond = new DateTime(utcNow.Year, utcNow.Month, utcNow.Day, 
        utcNow.Hour, utcNow.Minute, utcNow.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var localNow = DateTime.Now;

    var utcNowSerialized = SerializeDateTime(utcNow);
    var utcRoundedToSecondSerialized = SerializeDateTime(utcRoundedToSecond);
    var localNowSerialized = SerializeDateTime(localNow);

    Console.WriteLine("Serialization tests:");
    Console.WriteLine("UTC \t\t\t{0}", utcNowSerialized);
    Console.WriteLine("UTC rounded to seconds \t{0}", utcRoundedToSecondSerialized);
    Console.WriteLine("Local \t\t\t{0}", localNowSerialized);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Deserialization tests:");
    Console.WriteLine("UTC \t\t\t{0}", DeserializeDateTime(utcNowSerialized).ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine("UTC rounded to seconds \t{0}", DeserializeDateTime(utcRoundedToSecondSerialized).ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine("Local \t\t\t{0}", DeserializeDateTime(localNowSerialized).ToString("o"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string SerializeDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(dateTime);
}
private static DateTime DeserializeDateTime(string str)
{
    return (DateTime)TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString(str,typeof(DateTime));
}
```

It outputs:

```
Serialization tests:
UTC                     2017-03-21T21:24:41.1494902Z
UTC rounded to seconds  2017-03-21T21.24.41Z
Local                   2017-03-21T22.24.41.1494902+01:00

Deserialization tests:
UTC                     2017-03-21T22:24:41.1494902+01:00
UTC rounded to seconds  2017-03-21T22:24:41.0000000+01:00
Local                   2017-03-20T23:00:00.0000000+01:00
```

Apart from the dot as time separator, local `DateTime` lost time information after deserialization. On Windows, you can achieve the same results if you change date time settings to use HH.mm.ss and HH.mm instead of setting thread culture.
Is this Ok? Am I missing something? I would expect the time separator to be `:`, or at least to be consistent using the same culture. I am assuming `JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601` tells `TypeSerializer` to use ISO8601, and that ISO8601 is not culture dependent and does not allow dot as time separator.

Comment: `TypeSerializer.SerializeToString` invokes [`DateTimeSerializer.ToShortestXsdDateTimeString`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DateTimeSerializer.cs#L443), and that (independently of `JsConfig.DateHandler`) uses `.ToString()` without a culture. The ISO handler is considered only on *deserialization*. This seems like a bug to me. (Although why it behaves "correctly" with fractional seconds isn't clear to me, essentially the same code is invoked with different patterns that are both localizable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization should be using InvariantCulture so I've updated `DateTimeSerializer.ToShortestXsdDateTimeString()` to use InvariantCulture where it was missing (highlighted by @JeroenMostert in comments) in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/0c970d380154d9b4033f95cfb79ac45ad94844d6).

This change is available from v4.5.7+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and to @JeroenMostert for his response. I have tested that pre-release library and Utc dates without fractional seconds are still serialized with dots, although now everything is deserialized correctly. On your commit, I see you have left out some `ToString` calls without culture on that function. Specifically, I think [this one](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DateTimeSerializer.cs#L473) causes the Utc without fractional seconds to have dots. Is that intentional?

Comment: @M.Striata Good catch, all `DateTime.ToString()` should be now using InvariantCulture from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/f6ae6af67244c8c9e44b6a5fbc30b7d4bee1c1c5) which you can now re-download on MyGet by [clearing the NuGet package cache](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages).

Comment: Great! Works like a charm now. Thank you very much.